# Problemas para renderizar na tela no React Native

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, react-navigation

Estou com problemas ao colocar na tela um simples "Página main" o que está errado no código? (no console não aparece nenhum erro)

**Arquivo main.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

export default class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Página Main</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

**Arquivo index.js**

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './src';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

**Arquivo routes.js**

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Main from './pages/main'

export default creacteStackNavigator({
    Main
})
```

Comment: Como está seu componente `App`? E você não está criando as rotas de maneira correta, veja a documentação do [`createStackNavigator`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/)

Answer (score 0):

**De acordo com a [documentação](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/), em seu arquivo routes.js é necessário configura-lo parecido com isso:**

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Você precisa importar seu componente(Tela) e incluir em component={Tela}